# Get the data of a PUT request NodeJS http

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I am trying to get the data of a PUT request from a http server. I've tried the following:

```js
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer(async (req, res) => {
    const body = await new Promise(resolve => {
       const data = [];

       req.on('data', chunk => {
           data.push(chunk);
       });

       req.on('end', () => {
           resolve(data.join(''));
       });
   });

   console.log(body);
});

server.listen(80);
```

But when I make a PUT request to this server with the `name` 'Test' and the `value` 'Test' I get the following response:

```
------WebKitFormBoundary5irMnjtb69WOI025
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Test"

Test
------WebKitFormBoundary5irMnjtb69WOI025--
```

How do I make a JSON object of this?

Comment: Sounds like you are wanting to put an api together. Using one of the various node frameworks available that have routing and request handling built in would make this much simpler

Comment: Please also add to your question how you're sending the PUT request.